# Access Android Manifest attributes in Java

Tags: android, manifest

This is a sample manifest. Is it possible to access the attribute versionCode and versionName from Java? How?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    [...]

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep:

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo (context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo (context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

Answer (score 2):

for version code:

```
int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

for version name:

```
String versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```