# Reading application label and name from the Manifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

How can retrieve the following information from the manifest of an installed application?

```xml
activity android:label="Movie Player" 
android:name=".MoviePlayer"
```

Answer (score 3):

The [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) class gives access to the contents of a manifest, it contains [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) objects (among others) which have the fields you need.

Comment: Mi dispiace che mi può aiutare? Ho provato: ApplicationInfo a = null; String name = a.className; tv2.append (nome);

Comment: Here's a short example for using the PackageInfo class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557108/access-android-manifest-attributes-in-java. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to read: - <activity android:label="Movie Player" android:name=".MoviePlayer">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>

Comment: I would like to read the following attributes of the manifest of an app installed:  <activity android:label="Movie Player" android:name=".MoviePlayer">
</activity>

Comment: PackageInfo pack = null; ActivityInfo [] info = pack.activities; To use it tells me to set the flag GET_ACTIVITIES, but I do not know how.How to take hours information from the array of ActivityInfo?

Answer (score 1):

To read the application label from manifest use [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) Class

Kotlin Code

```
packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,0).applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
```