# How to show git-describe in React Native app?

Tags: android, ios, git, react-native, git-describe

I generally like to automatically bake-in the results of a `git describe --always --dirty` in any website, app, etc I am developing so that I can easily trace behaviors. Right now, I can't figure out a way to get this in a React Native app.

I am using Android, but am certainly looking for a solution to both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using a mix of other existing answers:

1. [Call git-describe during the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097263/automatically-versioning-android-project-from-git-describe-with-android-studio-g/18021756#18021756) to access from gradle
2. [Call PackageManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557108/access-android-manifest-attributes-in-java/9557142#9557142) to access the gradle config from Java
3. [Then use a React NativeModule in Java](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to access from JS

Update (3 years later): Here's a [minimal diff](https://github.com/TinyTheBrontosaurus/ultra-clock/commit/e0b4cc0277615e09a7840f96c2aebfbfe0128d7c) that shows how to implement in Android.